# I'm trying to do a post request in Airtable but I get blocked by CORS policy

Tags: airtable

I'm creating an extension on Airtable and I need to do a post request but whenever I try to send it I get blocked by CORS. I think is because as a client I shouldn't be able to do it without permission but is there any way to do it on the server side? I have access to the API

I try with axios but it didn't work.

Comment: Verify that the server is sending the correct CORS headers. The server should send the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers', and 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' headers, as appropriate.